# Can't convert UTF8 to default encoding

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8

I am trying to download a file over a RESTful Webservice and then save the file on the computer.

I am using an PDF-File to test the code. I found out the data is UTF-8 encoded so i tried encoding it back to default, because i found out by reading the pdf file locally and writing it back again that it works that way.

Here is my code:

```
IConsumerRequest getDocumentRequest = class.consumerSession
    .Request()
    .ForMethod("GET")
    .ForUri(new Uri(class.apiEndpoint + "/1/documents/" + id))
    .SignWithToken(class.accessToken);

string test = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\\test.pdf", Encoding.Default);

byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(getDocumentRequest.ToString());
string data = Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes);

MessageBox.Show(test.Substring(0, 120) + "\n\n" + data.Substring(0, 120));

SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();

saveFileDialog.FileName = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();

if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(saveFileDialog.FileName, bytes);
}
```

Comparing the string shows the following (second line):
[Local String vs String from Webservice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9ySr.png)

I already tried several ways to convert the string without any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work with HttpWebResponse:

```
HttpWebResponse webResponse = getDocumentRequest.ToWebResponse();

Stream stream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(UTF8);
StreamReader loResponseStream = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream(), enc);

string serverResponse = loResponseStream.ReadToEnd();

SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();

saveFileDialog.FileName = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();

if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog.FileName, serverResponse, Encoding.Default);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Encoding.Convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdcak6ye.aspx) method.

```
byte[] converted = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default, bytes);
```

Comment: Thanks but using this has exactly the same effect.

Comment: @TimoRzipa - What happens if you use the [WriteAllBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143376(v=vs.110).aspx) overload that takes in the encoding type as the last parameter?

Comment: There is no overload which also takes the encoding type. Bytes are not encoded in any way, so the problem has to be somewhere in the strings. I think maybe its not even my fault but a problem of the web service.

Comment: Apologies, I meant WriteAllText